# angular 4.X.X keyValueDiffer - how to use it?

Tags: angular, deprecated

As the title states, I am trying to understand how to properly use the keyValueDiffer in Angulars later versions. The problem is not the functionality itselves, but when I'm creating it, it says that create() is depricated due to deprication of ChangeDetectorRef.

```
this.diff = this.keyValueDiffer.find(obj).create(null);
```

How should it nowdays be used?

Tried it on Angular 4.1.3 and 4.3.3

https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffer

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *do* with it?

Comment: So, the usage should be that I have an object, that I want to performe change detection on (the object does not change, only values in it). I want to set up an origional value for the object and then in ngDoCheck() preform a manual change detection.

Comment: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/04/angular2-change-detection/ has a very good example of this

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include some useful context, with external resources only as further reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  DoCheck,
  KeyValueDiffers,
  KeyValueDiffer,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck
{    
   private _objDiff: { [any: string]: KeyValueDiffer<string, any> };
   private _dataToWatch: { [any: string]: any };

   public constructor(
      private _keyValueDiffers: KeyValueDiffers)
   {
      this._objDiff = {};
   }

   public ngOnInit(): void
   {
      this._dataToWatch = // get the data from some where...
      this._keyValueDiffers.find(this._dataToWatch).create();
   }

   public ngDoCheck(): void
   {
      const changes = this._objDiff.diff(this._dataToWatch);
      if(changes)
      {
         changes.forEachChangedItem((change) =>
         {
            if (change.currentValue != change.previousValue)
            {
               console.log("Value was changed!");
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

For more info see: 
1. https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck 
2. https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffer 
3. https://angular.io/api/core/KeyValueDiffers

Please notice that an Array change detection is done in a different way using the `IterableDiffers` and the `IterableDiffer` services (instead of `KeyValueDiffers` and `KeyValueDiffer`)